# Supporting Airport codes in geocode & calculate route

Tags: here-api

Is there any API to get geocode for airport code?

For ex: if I need to calculate time from home(say its Malibu) to LAX(Los Angeles Intl. Airport), Ideally I would follow below steps:

1. Get my home address geo location(via geocoder)
2. Get LAX geo location(via geocoder)
3. Use above as source and destination in "calculateroute".

However when I use "LAX" in geocoder, its gives some place in CHE(Switzerland).
If I append with country(USA), its listing some other place in Georgia.

*https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=MY-APP-ID&app_code=MY-APP-CODEgen=9&searchtext=LAX

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=MY-APP-ID&app_code=MY-APP-CODEgen=9&searchtext=LAX,USA*

Is there any alternate way to do it OR the only way is for me to maintain a map of IATA airport codes with their geo coordinates and use it directly in calculateroute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the geocode of an Airport: 
Use Landmark geocoding: categoryids=4581

**categoryids**

xs:integer
Limit landmark results to one or more categories. Examples:

```
Highway exits: 116
Airports: 4581
Tourist attractions: 7999
```

**Example:** 
http://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/search.json?categoryids=4581&gen=8&jsonattributes=1&language=en-US&maxresults=20&searchtext=LAX&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}

Read more at developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-search.html